# Automatically import 3rd party go packages

Tags: go, goland

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically download all the imports.
So let's assume I need to use `github.com/gorilla/mux` and several other packages in my code base. Should I manually go to my `~/go/src` and run `go get repo` or is there a smarter way of doing dependency management. I am using Goland IDE for my development.

Comment: Starting from go 1.11 you can do this: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: Use of modules (as in @oakad s comment) is recommended now because you can more easily version those libraries. `go get` (by default) just grabs whatever is current. Also, you don't need to `cd` to your `$GOHOME` to use `go get`, you can call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> if there is a way to automatically download all the imports

You can download all imported pkgs and their dependencies by running `go get` from the command line.

> I am using Goland IDE for my development

I'm using Goland too. When imports can't be found (ie the import path is highlighted in red), you can place your typing caret over it and press `alt + enter` and select `go get ...` from the popup window to automatically import.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something like `dep`. But the above suggestion was also helpful. Thanks! https://github.com/golang/dep

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaces:

- Simply `go get github.com/gorilla/mux` which will download sources in your `$GOPATH` and will be resolved automatically when compiling
- Use dependency management (godep, glide[deprecated])
- Use modules (experimental feature in Go 1.11 - Module. [Check more here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules))

If you want a good and stable solution, use `dep` (.First you have to install it, then run:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/path/to/project
dep init
dep ensure -add github.com/gorilla/mux
```

You will see a new folder `vendor` in your project and 2 new dependency configuration files `Gopkg.lock` and `Gopkg.toml`.
Read more about godep [here](https://github.com/tools/godep).

Then run your main file as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dep` package manager which will go through your code and automatically import all the packages you use in you code. If you are working with >go1.11 I would suggest to use newly added `go mod`.